# Swagger setting path parameter data type

Tags: java, annotations, swagger, openapi

I am trying to set the path parameter as below

```
@PUT
    @Path("{myParam}/myEndpoint")
    @ApiOperation(value = SwaggerApiConst.EVENT)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(dataType = "long", name = "myParam", paramType = "path")
       })
    public Response group( @PathParam("myParam") Long myParam, SomeObj someObj) {
```

Trying to set the data type of parentAlarm as **long**, but it appears as integer in the swagger.json file.

```
'/myApi/{myParam}/myEndpoint':
    put:
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - type: integer
          name: myEndpoint
          in: path
          required: true
        - name: body
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/SomeObj'
```

swagger version used is

```
<swagger.version>1.5.0</swagger.version>
```

@ApiImplicitParam seems to have no effect here. Is there an alternative ?

Answer (score 1):

Swagger supports only integer and number datatypes. Long is specified as int64 and integer as int32. You can read more about the data types here - https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/

Comment: But is there a way to display int64 in the output ? like below using ApiImplicitParam  or any other annotation:

            "type" : "integer",
            "format" : "int64"

Comment: This works for me using springfox-swagger 2.9.1. ApiImplicitParams and ApiParam displays the format - "type":"integer","format":"int64". Maybe you should try with a later version of swagger.